# SQL query takes too long to run in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've the following query which works absolutely fine in Oracle developer

```
select TRIM(a.filterh) 
from CHANNEL a,GENRE b
where b.label = 'M001CL01_ABC' 
  and a.s_r_id = b.r_id 
  and a.filterh in (select c.filterh 
                    from CHANNEL c, GENRE d 
                    where d.label = 'M001AL03' and c.s_r_id = d.r_id)
```

I just tried to simplify the above query and some syntax change for SQL developer and the below query takes a lot of time to run in SSMS

```
select TRIM(a.filterh) 
from CHANNEL a 
inner join GENRE b on a.s_r_id = b.r_id
where b.label = 'M001CL01_ABC' 
  and a.filterh in (select c.filterh 
                    from CHANNEL c
                    inner join GENRE d on c.s_r_id = d.r_id
                    where d.label = 'M001AL03')
```

I just wish to understand what am I doing wrong here, how can I improve my query and why the SQL query takes a lot of time.

Thank you.

Comment: "doesn't" i s not very descriptive.  Do you get an error?  Unexpected results?  What is happening?  Note that in both databases there are probably better approaches than what is being done here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated my question, can you let me know what is the better way  for the SQL query?

Comment: It would help to see the table schemas and existing indexes. The `in` clause looks suspcious and could probably be replaced with just an `exists` against the `Genre` table?

Comment: I'll post the schema shortly, data are in lakhs so can't post them

Comment: Please add table **and index** definitions, please also share the query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the query. Please keep in mind that since there is no data to test on, I couldn't test it propertly, so it is up to you to check it out, whether it could be compiled.

Here what I've done is just removed the subquery because they often lead to mistakes of query optimizer

```
select TRIM(a.filterh) 
  from CHANNEL a 
  join GENRE b on a.s_r_id = b.r_id
  join CHANNEL c on a.filterh = c.filterh 
  join GENRE d on c.s_r_id = d.r_id
 where b.label = 'M001CL01_ABC' 
   and d.label = 'M001AL03'
```

Another point to mention is that performance issues may depend on many things. For example quantity of rows, indexes, storage device etc. If you post a similar quesion in future it is better to provide us with execution plans and statistics turned on while executing the query.

If query runs slowly, ON A TEST INSTANCE try to create an index on channel.filterg and another one on genre.label columns.

Comment: This query can be executed, just checking if I can get the desired output.
I'll comment back shortly.

Comment: @m_beta check my updated answer if no solution from all provided above works for you

Answer (score 0):

See if `EXISTS` instead of `IN` improves the situation any better.

```
select TRIM(a.filterh) 
from CHANNEL a 
inner join GENRE b on a.s_r_id = b.r_id and b.label = 'M001CL01_ABC' 
where exists(select *
            from CHANNEL c
            inner join GENRE d on c.s_r_id = d.r_id and d.label = 'M001AL03'
            where a.filterh = c.filterh)
```

Comment: I know about `Exists` but can you help me understand how is the `a.filterh in` part of my query handled in your version

Comment: @m_beta, it is moved into the `where` part of the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can probably do the following, hard to say for sure without seeing the data and being able to test:

```
select TRIM(a.filterh) 
from CHANNEL a 
inner join GENRE b on a.s_r_id = b.r_id
where b.label = 'M001CL01_ABC' 
    and exists (select * from GENRE g where g.r_id=a.s_r_id and g.label='M001AL03')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use aggregation in either database:

```
select TRIM(c.filterh) 
from CHANNEL c join
     GENRE g
     on g.s_r_id = c.r_id
where g.label in ('M001CL01_ABC', 'M001AL03')
group by TRIM(c.filterh)
having count(distinct g.label) = 2;
```

You should learn to use *meaningful* table aliases.  Arbitrary letters such as `a` and `b` do not help anyone understand the query.